# envia datos null radio button, laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

soy nuevo en esto de laravel, y tengo un problema al enviar datos con los radio button, los envía como null.

```js
...

controller.php 

public function create()
    {
      $salas=DB::table('sala')->get();

      return view ('equipos.accesorios.create',['salas'=>$salas]);
    }

    public function store(AccesorioFormRequest $request)
    {
      $accesorio = new Accesorio;
      $accesorio->id_sala=$request->get('id_sala');
      $accesorio->control_remoto=$request->get('control_remoto');
      $accesorio->adaptador=$request->get('adaptador');
      $accesorio->botonera=$request->get('botonera');
      $accesorio->internet=$request->get('internet');
      $accesorio->hdmi=$request->get('hdmi');
      $accesorio->monitor=$request->get('monitor');
      $accesorio->pc=$request->get('pc');
      $accesorio->data=$request->get('data');
      $accesorio->cantidad_vga=$request->get('cantidad_vga');
      $accesorio->save();
      return Redirect::to('equipos/accesorios');
    }
```

```html
...
view.blade.php

{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'equipos/accesorios','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
    {{Form::token()}}

    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Salas</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="id_sala">
              @foreach ($salas as $sal)
                <option value="{{$sal->idsala}}">{{$sal->nombre}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>info</th>
  <th>info2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>


<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

        <h4>Control Remoto</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline" for="si">
          <input name="select_cr" id="si" type="radio" value="si">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" for="no">
          <input name="select_cr" id="no" type="radio" value="no">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Adaptador</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_ad" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_ad" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

        <h4>Botonera</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_bot" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_bot" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Internet</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_int" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_int" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>


      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

        <h4>HDMI</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_hdm" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_hdm" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Monitor</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_mon" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_mon" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

        <h4>PC</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_pc" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_pc" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
<td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Data</h4>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_da" id="si" type="radio" value="SI">SI
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="select_da" id="no" type="radio" value="NO">NO
        </label>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="vga">Cantidad VGA</label>
          <input name="vga" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{old('vga')}}" placeholder="Cantidad Vga">
        </div>
      </div>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
           <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
       </div>
     </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando intentas recuperar los datos tienes que hacer referencia al atributo `name`, no al título que le has añadido (date cuenta de que es otra etiqueta totalmente diferente). Por lo tanto sería:

```
$accesorio->botonera=$request->get('select_bot');
$accesorio->internet=$request->get('select_int');
...
```

Ya que tienes establecidos los `inputs` de la siguiente manera:

```
<input name="select_bot" id="si" type="radio" value="SI"> <!-- Input de botonera -->
<input name="select_int" id="si" type="radio" value="SI"> <!-- Input de Internet -->
...
```

Y así con todos los radio-buttons que tengas.